# In Clang, can I access the SourceManager when writing a custom ASTMatcher?

Tags: c++, clang, code-analysis, llvm-clang

I'm trying to upgrade my [AutoFFI](https://github.com/AutoFFI/AutoFFI) project by making it more elegant and use Clang's [ASTMatchers](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html) more extensively. I'd like to create a matcher that filters on the file path that was specified. Is it possible to do such a thing, or do I need to add custom logic outside of the matcher for this to work? As far as I can see, there's no way to get the `SourceManager` and use it to create a `FullSourceLoc`, but maybe I'm missing something.

Some relevant links:

- https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FullSourceLoc.html
- https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/f3b7928366f63b51ffc97e74f8afcff497c57e8d/include/clang/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchersMacros.h#L28

If someone could tell me whether this is a limitation to Clang's ASTMatcher API or not I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, I've found the answer by looking at the source of `isExpansionInMainFile`:

```cpp
AST_POLYMORPHIC_MATCHER(isExpansionInMainFile,
                        AST_POLYMORPHIC_SUPPORTED_TYPES(Decl, Stmt, TypeLoc)) {
  auto &SourceManager = Finder->getASTContext().getSourceManager();
  return SourceManager.isInMainFile(
      SourceManager.getExpansionLoc(Node.getBeginLoc()));
}
```

Turns out I missed the `getASTContext` in `MatchFinder`, which holds on to the source manager.